# Matrix of Structs Initialization and Filling - C

Tags: c, matrix, struct

I need to make a matrix of structs that have a type

```
struct colorPixelData_t {
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
};
```

And I'm trying to initialize my values like this:

```
struct colorPixelData_t **initColorMatrix(struct colorPixelData_t **b, int height, int width)
{
        int i, j;
        b = malloc(height * width * sizeof(struct colorPixelData_t));
        assert(b);
        for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
                        b[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(struct colorPixelData_t));
        }
        return b;
}
```

And I'm trying to manipulate the data below. Basically, I'm reading in a bmp file and part of the format is the pixel data, which I read into a void * array and then memcpy it into an unsigned char * array, then the unsigned char *array to the matrix of structs. Each 3 bytes holds one rgb value per pixel, ie bytes 0-2 might hold 200, 0, 0 to form an rgb of (200,0,0) for pixel [0,0] - hence the matrix of structs [pixel x, pixel y] -> red, green, blue.

```
struct colorPixelData_t **getColorPixelInfo(struct colorPixelData_t **colorPixelData, void *colorPixelDataArr, int imageSize, int height, int width)
{
        unsigned char *unsCharArr = malloc(imageSize);
        assert(unsCharArr);
        memcpy(unsCharArr, colorPixelDataArr, imageSize);

        int counter = 0;
        int iteratorByThree = 0;
        for (int i = height - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                        if (iteratorByThree == 0)
                                colorPixelData[i][j] -> red = (int) unsCharArr[counter];
                        else if (iteratorByThree == 1)
                                colorPixelData[i][j] -> green = (int) unsCharArr[counter];
                        else {
                                colorPixelData[i][j] -> blue = (int) unsCharArr[counter];
                                iteratorByThree = 0;
                        }
                        counter++;
                        iteratorByThree++;
                }
        }
        return colorPixelData;
}
```

When I compile this, it gives me these errors:

```
bmp.c: In function ‘initColorMatrix’:
bmp.c:678:33: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct colorPixelData_t’ from type ‘void *’
                         b[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(struct colorPixelData_t));
                                 ^
bmp.c: In function ‘getColorPixelInfo’:
bmp.c:694:54: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct colorPixelData_t’)
                                 colorPixelData[i][j] -> red = (int) unsCharArr[counter];
                                                      ^~
bmp.c:696:54: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct colorPixelData_t’)
                                 colorPixelData[i][j] -> green = (int) unsCharArr[counter];
                                                      ^~
bmp.c:698:54: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct colorPixelData_t’)
                                 colorPixelData[i][j] -> blue = (int) unsCharArr[counter];
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Should use `.` instead of `->`.

Comment: `b` is an array of structs, not an array of pointers. Why are you calling `malloc()` inside the loop?

Comment: also, the inner malloc is wrong of course, you should read again how to allocate a 2d array.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I used dot notation and that took away those compiling errors. I'll try and re allocate memory for the matrix, I'm getting a seg fault right now

Comment: I redid the memory allocation with old code I used for a 2D matrix and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks Antii for pointing out how trash I am at remembering how to allocate memory for it lol